# Terminating program from a thread contained in try/except block

Tags: python, while-loop, terminate

can someone help me with terminating this program from if statement. I can't get it done. I've tried to this with sys.quit, but it seems to be not suitable for try/except block and I can't break out of the loop within thread. I could do this in the run() method, but it's a little bit useless to build a thread and then try to do something outside of it. It feels like there is something wrong about it. Here's code:

```
class TradingBot:

def init(self) -> None:
    self.api = tradeapi.REST(key_id=API_KEY, secret_key=SECRET_KEY, base_url=BASE_URL, api_version='v2')

def simple_thread(self):

    try:
        account = self.api.get_account()
        clock = self.api.get_clock()

        balance_change = float(account.equity) - float(account.last_equity)

        condition_1 = balance_change > 0
        condition_2 = balance_change < 0

        if condition_1:

            pass
            #Figure out something to quit if condition 1 is met

        elif condition_2:

            pass
            #Figure out something to quit if condition 2 is met


    except:

        print('Some error has occured')

def run(self):

    while True:

        execute = threading.Thread(target=self.simple_thread())
        execute.start()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Why do you have a bare `except` clause?

Comment: It's just a sketch, so nothing big here. This is not related to the problem I have. I guess.

Answer (score 0):

[`sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) attempts to exit by throwing a [`SystemExit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit) exception, which is caught by the bare `except` clause. I'm not sure why you need the [`try`/`except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) at all, but you should probably at least change it to catch only [`Exception`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#Exception), which, unlike [`BaseException`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException), only includes normal exceptions, not special ones such as `SystemExit`.

Comment: I see, thank you for your help. It's really appriciated. And I need this try/except block, because my internet connection is really bad, so sometimes it has these lapses, where it can't connect with API.

Comment: @DominikPucuła I see, that makes sense, just be careful that it doesn't get messed up if the disconnect happens in the middle of the code. What exception class does it raise when it disconnects? Try only handling that exception.